# Email verification during onboarding that requires internal approval

Tags: onboarding, signup

I'm designing a sign-up flow for a clinic management platform (browser, desktop and mobile friendly) that is dedicated for business owners to sign-up for their company. The one registering will be the owner account that manages everything, like a super admin of the company when using my product. Think as if I'm Stripe, the payment gateway provider.

To be adherent to the local laws, we will require the business to be a legitimate business, and we will approve it manually before user can complete the sign up process.

In summary, the flow I drafted was:

1. User land on sign-in/sign-up page. User click on sign-up
2. User will see fields to put in their business name, business registration number, attach soft-copy of their business registration registry with their local council.
3. User submits and receives and email on the copy of response.
4. Validation team will receive an email to review and approve or reject the invitation. Validation team approves it after doing due diligence, including calling the user over phone.
5. User receives an email that it's approved and in the email, user will click on the CTA button to continue the sign-up process
6. User lands to the page to create their password and clicks 'Continue'

Now I'm stuck what's after (6). Should I......

- A: Land user to the logged-in landing page, which is the Dashboard
  and congratulate them. (Risk: what if user have a typo in their
  email? Or it turns out to be an abuser who have stolen a soft-copy of
  business license and trying to imitate them).
- B: Proceed to verify
  user's email, where an email will be sent to the user > user click on
  the link and completes sign up > land user to the logged-in landing
  page. Risk: clunky flow that brings user off the platform for the second time)

---

Now I've also ran through this with my Product Designer, should we were to choose A. Could we have:

Opt 1 - During (2) above, incorporate the flow to force user to verify their email first like in (B) before they reach (3)

Opt 2 - Maintain status quo above

All cents are welcomed!
-Kenny

Answer (score 0):

Given the need for thorough validation and adherence to local laws, Option B seems to be a more secure and user-friendly approach. Here's a refined suggestion for Option B:

Option B Refined:

Consider Using Sniper Link which will land them directly to the mail.